# Fixed navbar overlaps <div> element, causes Navbar to stop working

Tags: html, css

So I've created the Navbar which jumps to sections on the page via clicking. It works for my 'projects' and 'contact' sections but when I click 'about' the navbar jumps to it, but becomes transparent and unclickable. I tried adding a padding-top X px; to the 'about' element, but it still doesn't work.

Code is as follows in Codepen:
HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="fluid-container">
<h2> My Web Portfolio</h2>

<!--Creates the Navigation bar -->

<div class="navbar">
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="#projects">Projects</a>
<a href="#contact" style="float:right">Contact</a>
</div>

<!-- this creates the About section-->
<div class="main">
<div id=about>
<h3>Blank</h3>
</div>

<!-- This creates the 'project' section of the webpage-->

<div id=projects>
<h3><pre>My tribute page to Neil Armstrong<pre></h3>
<a href="#"><img border="0" alt="My Tribute page" align="center" src="#"/>                
     </a>
</div>

<!--contact section-->
<div id=contact>
<h3>Contact me via Facebook, Twitter, and Instagram!<h3>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook" ></a>
   <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
   <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
     </div>
   </div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color:turquoise;
padding-top:25px;
}

h2 {  
text-align:center;
}
.navbar {
overflow:hidden;
background-color:#333;
position:fixed;
top:0px;
 width:100%;
 }
.navbar a {
float:left;
display:block;
color:#f2f2f2;
text-align:center;
padding:14px 16px;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:17px;
}

.main {
padding:16px;
margin-top:65px;
}

#projects {
position:relatve;
width:150px;
height:100px;
margin-top:200px;
margin-left:150px;
}

#contact {
position:relatve;
text-align:center;
margin-top:800px;
}

#about{
position:relative;
text-align:center;
padding-top:25px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you add the codepen link?

Comment: Here it is

https://codepen.io/KyleHerkert/pen/LWyvpJ

Answer (score 1):

When the page jumps to *about*, the sections obscure the nav bar. If you set a z-index to #main and the nav bar, you can ensure the navbar is always above the sections. I hope this helps.

```css
body {
  background-color: turquoise;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0
  margin-top: 65px;
}

#projects {
  position: relatve;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

#contact {
  position: relatve;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 800px;
}

#about {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="fluid-container">
<h2> My Web Portfolio</h2>

<!--Creates the Navigation bar -->

<div class="navbar">
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="#projects">Projects</a>
<a href="#contact" style="float:right">Contact</a>
</div>

<!-- this creates the About section-->
<div class="main">
<div id=about>
<h3>Blank</h3>
</div>

<!-- This creates the 'project' section of the webpage-->

<div id=projects>
<h3><pre>My tribute page to Neil Armstrong<pre></h3>
<a href="#"><img border="0" alt="My Tribute page" align="center" src="#"/>                
     </a>
</div>

<!--contact section-->
<div id=contact>
<h3>Contact me via Facebook, Twitter, and Instagram!<h3>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook" ></a>
   <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
   <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
     </div>
   </div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it right up! Guess I should go read up on index's.

Comment: Yep =). An element with a higher index will appear on top of an element with a lower index. Be sure that the position (relative, absolute, etc...) of both elements are set, though.